# Calling to ajax multiple times from javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
for(var x=0 ; x<=23 ; x++)
{
    AjaxRequest16 = null;
    AjaxRequest16 = getXmlHttpRequestObject(); // method here to load the request

    if(AjaxRequest16.readyState == 4 || AjaxRequest16.readyState == 0) 
    {
        AjaxRequest16.open("GET", "ajax.php?id=16&AreaID=" +encodeURIComponent(AreaID)+ "&month=" 
                +encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("cboMonths").value)+ "&TimeSlot=" +encodeURIComponent(x), true);

        AjaxRequest16.send(null);

        AjaxRequest16.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(AjaxRequest16.readyState == 4) 
            {
                var innerHTML = AjaxRequest16.responseText.toString();
                /* Retrieve data from the server and display. */ 
                document.getElementById("divTime"+x).innerHTML = innerHTML;

            }/* end if */            
        }/* end function */            
    }/* end if */            

}/* end if */
```

I'm trying to call ajax multiple times to load data in a set of divs: 24 of them, they start with divTime0, divTime1, divTime2, divTime3...... divTime23. Each time its called, the value for the TimeSlot corresponds with the div e.g. TimeSlot=0 goes in divTime0.

I know the ajax calls here are overriding each other but have no idea how to solve it without writing out 24 blocks of code to get it working. N.B. this **is** working if i execute singularly without the for loop but it will just populate 1 of the 24 divs

The following code worked to load 24 divs with images:

```
for(var x=0 ; x<=23 ; x++)
    document.getElementById("timeanalysisimg"+x).src="ajax.php?id=15&AreaID=" +encodeURIComponent(AreaID);
```

I'm trying to do something similar without having to write unnecessary code. Any ideas?

**I got it working**. Just pasting the solution

```
for(var x=0 ; x<=9 ; x++)
{
    test(x, AreaID); // calling the function which resides externally to the loop
}
```

An external method:

```
function test(x, AreaID)
{
        var AjaxRequest16 = null;
        AjaxRequest16 = getXmlHttpRequestObject();

        if(AjaxRequest16.readyState == 4 || AjaxRequest16.readyState == 0) 
        {
            AjaxRequest16.open("GET", "ajax.php?id=16&AreaID=" +encodeURIComponent(AreaID)+ "&month=" 
                    +encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("cboMonths").value)+ "&TimeSlot=" +encodeURIComponent(x), true);

            AjaxRequest16.send(null);

            AjaxRequest16.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(AjaxRequest16.readyState == 4) 
                {
                    var innerHTML = AjaxRequest16.responseText.toString();
                    /* Retrieve data from the server and display. */ 
                    document.getElementById("divTime"+x).innerHTML = innerHTML;

                }      
            }
        }    
}
```

Comment: Can't you get all the data at once?

Comment: Why don't you make one Ajax call which loads the data into an array?

Comment: I could have done it that way but started writing the code from ajax and then back. The code there is so big now I can't do that. Each time the for loop loops, it passes a different timeslot number to ajax method which is returning sizeable data

Comment: if you do it `asynchronous = false`, you browser would freeze until you get all the data, and this not accpetable

Comment: check my answer out, this is what you want, without using `asynchronous = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the block into a function:

```
for(var x=0 ; x<=23 ; x++)
{
  (function(x) {
    var AjaxRequest16 = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
    //rest of the code

  }(x));
} //end of for loop
```

Comment: I tried this exactly as you put it but it didn't work. However when I put the function external and call it, it worked beautifully

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
for(var x=0 ; x<=23 ; x++)
{
    req(x);

}

function req(x){
    var AjaxRequest16 = null;
    AjaxRequest16 = getXmlHttpRequestObject(); // method here to load the request

    if(AjaxRequest16.readyState == 4 || AjaxRequest16.readyState == 0) 
    {
        AjaxRequest16.open("GET", "ajax.php?id=16&AreaID=" +encodeURIComponent(AreaID)+ "&month=" 
                +encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("cboMonths").value)+ "&TimeSlot=" +encodeURIComponent(x), true);

        AjaxRequest16.send(null);

        AjaxRequest16.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(AjaxRequest16.readyState == 4) 
            {
                var innerHTML = AjaxRequest16.responseText.toString();
                /* Retrieve data from the server and display. */ 
                document.getElementById("divTime"+x).innerHTML = innerHTML;

            }/* end if */            
        }/* end function */            
    }/* end if */            

}
```

Comment: `AjaxRequest16` would still be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I changed all the code, but it does exactly what you want, without using `asynchronous = false`, and browser freezing:

```
function ajaxRequest(url, callback) {
    var req = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) // if IE
    {
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    } else {
        throw ("No Ajax support!");
        return;
    }
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (typeof (callback) == "function") callback(req);
        }
    };
    req.send(null);
    return req;
}

function loadMyData() {
    var x = parseInt(arguments[0]);
    if (x > 23) {
        alert("all 24 is loaded!");
    }
    var url = "ajax.php?id=16&AreaID=" + encodeURIComponent(AreaID) +
        "&month=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("cboMonths").value) +
        "&TimeSlot=" + encodeURIComponent(x);
    var callback = Function('req', 'document.getElementById("divTime' + x + '").innerHTML =' +
        ' req.responseText;' +
        'loadMyData(' + x + ');');
    ajaxRequest(url, callback);
}

loadMyData(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make your ajax calls `asenkron false` try this:

```
for(var x=0 ; x<=23 ; x++)
    {
        AjaxRequest16 = null;
        AjaxRequest16 = getXmlHttpRequestObject(); // method here to load the request

        if(AjaxRequest16.readyState == 4 || AjaxRequest16.readyState == 0) 
        {
            AjaxRequest16.open("GET", "ajax.php?id=16&AreaID=" +encodeURIComponent(AreaID)+ "&month=" 
                    +encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("cboMonths").value)+ "&TimeSlot=" +encodeURIComponent(x), false);

            AjaxRequest16.send(null);

            AjaxRequest16.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(AjaxRequest16.readyState == 4) 
                {
                    var innerHTML = AjaxRequest16.responseText.toString();
                    /* Retrieve data from the server and display. */ 
                    document.getElementById("divTime"+x).innerHTML = innerHTML;

                }/* end if */            
            }/* end function */            
        }/* end if */            

    }/* end if */
```

Comment: Tried this but it isn't loading any data

Comment: do you get any console errors if so can you share them here please

Comment: if you do it `asynchronous = false`, you browser would freeze until you get all the data, and this not accpetable

Comment: but if dont make asynchronous = false you dont know which ajax call will successed first.and so your data will not loaded in the order that you give

Answer (score 0):

**Sequentially load content with ajax**

here is a simple ajax function for modern browsers (chrome,safari,ie10,android,ios)

```
function ajax(a,b,c){//url,function,just a placeholder
 c=new XMLHttpRequest;
 c.open('GET',a);
 c.onload=b;
 c.send()
}
```

and this is how you load content sequentially

```
var current=0,
    x=23;

function handler(){
 document.getElementById("divTime"+current).innerHTML=this.response;
 current++
 if(current<x){
  ajax('url.php?id='+current,handler)
 }
}

ajax('url.php?id='+current,handler);
```

this way you don't overwrite previous ajax calls.

---

Multiple simultaneous ajax calls is a bad solution.

anyway to achieve multiple ajax calls at the same time you need to create multiple ajax request functions.

```
 var ajaxcall=[];

 ajaxcall[0]=new XMLHttpRequest;
 ajaxcall[0].CUSTOMID=0;
 ajaxcall[0].open('GET','url.php?id='+0);
 ajaxcall[0].onload=function(){console.log(this.CUSTOMID,this.response)};
 ajaxcall[0].send();
```

Answer (score 0):

What it boils down to is the asynchronous nature of Ajax calls.
Each Ajax context must be kept alive until the request is over (completion or failure).

In your initial code, you use only one Ajax request context. The loop launches the first request, but then overwrites its context immediately with the second one long before the first was processed. When the server responds (a few milliseconds later), there is no handler left on the browser side to process the response (except for the 24th one).

What your workaround does is to create a different context and callback for each request, since your global function stores them in different closures.

However, as a result you will fire a hail of 24 Ajax requests simultaneously on the server, which is likely to cause unnecessary overhead, or even crashes if your PHP script does not expect to execute concurrently on the same request. Besides, synchronizing your code on completion of these requests will not be easy.

Here is what I use for my own apps :

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Ajax lite
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
function PageCache (target, void_contents)
{
    this.text = {};
    this.req  = {};
    this.void_contents = void_contents || 'void';
    this.target = target;
}

PageCache.prototype = {
    // synchronous load
    load: function (page)
    {
        if (!this.text[page]) this.text[page] = this._launch_request (page); 
        return this.text[page]; 
    },

    // asynchronous load
    fetch: function (page, action)
    {
        if (this.text[page])
        {
            action (this, page);
            return;
        }
        if (this.req[page]) return;
        this.req[page] = this._launch_request (page, 
            function(_this, _page, _action) {
                return function(){ 
                    _this._loader(_page,_action);
                    };
            }(this,page,action)); 
    },

    _launch_request: function (page, callback)
    {
        var req;
        try {
                req = window.XMLHttpRequest
                    ? new XMLHttpRequest()
                    : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        catch (e) {}
        req.open('GET', this.target.replace (/\$/, page), callback!=undefined);
        if (callback) req.onreadystatechange = callback;
        req.send(null);
        return callback ? req : this._get_result (req);
    },

    _get_result: function (req)
    {
        return (req.status < 400)
                ? req.responseText
                : this.void_contents;
    },

    _loader: function (page, action)
    {
        if (!this.req[page] || (this.req[page].readyState != 4)) return;
        this.text[page] = this._get_result (this.req[page])
        delete this.req[page];
        if (action) action (this.text[page], page);
    }
}
```

In your example, you could use it like so:

First, a bit of cleanup :

```
function compute_id (AreaID,x) {
return "id=16&AreaID=" 
      + encodeURIComponent(AreaID)
      + "&month=" 
      + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("cboMonths").value)
      + "&TimeSlot="
      + x; // I suspect all the encodeURIComponent() calls are unnecessary
}

var Ajax = new PageCache (
     'ajax.php?$',          // '$' will be replaced with fetch() parameter
     'error loading data'); // contents in case of request failure
```

1) simultaneous requests (not recommended)

```
for (var x = 0; x != 24 ; x++) {
    // store current x value in a closure
    var request_done = function (_x) {
        return function (responseText) {
            document.getElementById("divTime"+_x).innerHTML = responseText;
            }}(x);
    }
    Ajax.fetch (compute_id (AreaID,x), request_done);          
}
```

2) sequential blocking requests (very bad, don't do it unless your code cannot proceed without the data)

```
for (var x = 0; x != 24 ; x++) {
    document.getElementById("divTime"+x).innerHTML = 
        Ajax.load (compute_id (AreaID,x));          
}
```

3) sequential non-blocking requests

```
var AjaxCtx = { x:0, max:24};

// launch first request
Ajax.fetch (compute_id (AreaID, AjaxCtx.x), request_done);

function request_done (responseText) {
    document.getElementById("divTime"+AjaxCtx.x).innerHTML = responseText;

    // request completion triggers the next
    if (++AjaxCtx.x != AjaxCtx.max)
        Ajax.fetch (compute_id (AreaID,AjaxCtx.x), request_done);
}
```