# How to long poll a url in web application in background

Tags: html, ajax, servlets, long-polling

I want to long poll a URL in my web application in a background thread such that it sends the next request only when the response is achieved for the first request or the first request is timed out.

Comment: Except that threads have little to do with JavaScript programming, isn't that what Ajax is all about? Your XMLHttpRequest object should handle all the required events for you. Or is there something else your application specifically requires ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to poll anything, just catch the events fired by XMLHttpRequest objects. If for some reason your request takes a very long time to answer, you will eventually get a timeout.

As for serializing Ajax requests, you might want to have a look at [this similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801510/calling-to-ajax-multiple-times-from-javascript/20815769#20815769).